# Как реализовать перенос текста по слогам в TextView?

Tags: java, android, textview

Имеется ScrollView со множеством кликабельных TextView.
Текст выравниваю по ширине, используя библиотеку JustifiedTextView.
Размер текста достаточно крупный, поэтому промежутки между словами тоже большие, что негативно сказывается на комфортности чтения.
Вопрос в том, как можно реализовать перенос слов по слогам?

Уже несколько дней безрезультатно гуглю с разными запросами. Такое впечатление, что   либо никому не нужны переносы в словах, либо вопрос настолько тривиален, что его никто не задаёт.

Подскажите: куда копать?

Вот тестируемая (в оригинале использую стили) разметка:

```
    <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.uncopt.android.widget.text.justify.JustifiedTextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/stringOne"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:hyphenationFrequency="full"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/stringTwo"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:hyphenationFrequency="normal"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

compileSdkVersion 26

buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

minSdkVersion 23

targetSdkVersion 26
Тестирую на meizu с 7-м андроидом

Comment: Ну... Вот здесь, например, спрашивают обратное - как такое отключить: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45489409/3212712 Возможно у вас что-то не так с настройками текстовых полей? Покажите разметку и расскажите на какой версии ОС запускаете.

Comment: https://github.com/mfietz/JHyphenator это жава реализация общепринятого алгоритма деления слов для переноса как я понял.  Сам с этим не возился, подсказать больше ничего не могу,  но копать надо видимо туда

Answer (score 0):

Атрибут hyphenationFrequency позволяет управлять стратегией переноса слов по слогам. Значение none не будет делать автоматический перенос слов, normal сделает небольшую частоту переносов, а full, соответственно, задействует максимальное количество слов.